# Android NotificationCompat shows no largeicon in 2.3

Tags: android, notifications, android-notifications

I'm playing around notifications in android, and I'm wondering why NotificationCompat doesn't display Large Icon, and Number in Gingerbread as it does in Jellybean (see pics), I thought that was for that purpose that it was created ?

here is how I fire the notifications :

```
    @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Button btnShow = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnNotif);

    Intent intent = new Intent(this, NotificationReceiverActivity.class);
    PendingIntent pIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, 0);

    notificationManager =  (NotificationManager) this.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);


        NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
        .setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis())
        .setContentText("You are near your point of interest.")
        .setContentTitle("Proximity Alert!")
        .setSmallIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_menu_info_details)
        .setLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.orchide))
        .setAutoCancel(true)
        .setTicker("Proximity Alert!")
        .setNumber(10)
        .setContentIntent(pIntent)
        .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_LIGHTS| Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE| Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND);
        /*Create notification with builder*/
         notification=notificationBuilder.build();

        /*sending notification to system.Here we use unique id (when)for making different each notification
         * if we use same id,then first notification replace by the last notification*/
    btnShow.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            notificationManager.notify(1000, notification);
        }

    });



}
```

[image: Notification in gingerbread]

[image: Notification in Jelly bean]

Comment: Posting some code would make sense to provide solution of your problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Large icon is ignored on pre-honeycomb API levels.

[NotificationCompat.Builder documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/NotificationCompat.Builder.html) says:
*...On platform versions that don't offer expanded notifications, methods that depend on expanded notifications have no effect...*

If you look at the NotificationCompat.Builder source you'll see that large icon is used for honeycomb and above.

Comment: How come facebook's notification has a large icon on the right?